# How can I make AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync() use a modal dialog

Tags: wpf, azure-active-directory, adal

I am using AuthenticationContext in a WPF app to authenticate a user to Azure Active Directory. It works great as expected,

but the login dialog shown by the following code is not modal, meaning that it can easily end up hidden behind my WPF app.

Is there a way to force it to be modal?

var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, redirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always));

**Update:**
I am able to set the `ownerWindow` property of the `PlatformParameters` by supplying the window returned by

```
var window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(w => w.IsActive);
```

But this results in an error:

> Invalid owner window type. Expected types are IWin32Window or IntPtr

However, I have since discovered that the reason my dialog was not modal is that it's appearing *before* my main window has loaded. If my main window loads first, then the dialog is modal without me having to set the `ownerWindow` property of the `PlatformParameters`.

Comment: Pls see if `OwnerWindow` parameter explained in this link helps- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.platformparameters?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: @NSouth can you please explain what do you exactly want or you can show your code snippet if possible so that it would be quite easier to solve. Thanks